# With the tables "price" and "trans". where the "price" table has a price per product for each day. I want the latest price times the product

Tags: sql

Table 1, `price`, has product prices on a daily basis:

| Date | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-19 | Product A | 69.4792 |
| 2023-07-19 | Product B | 69.4792 |
| 2023-07-19 | Product C | 51.1961 |
| 2023-07-19 | Product D | 51.1961 |
| 2023-07-20 | Product A | 69.4792 |
| 2023-07-20 | Product B | 69.4792 |
| 2023-07-20 | Product C | 51.1961 |
| 2023-07-20 | Product D | 51.1961 |
| 2023-07-21 | Product A | 69.4792 |
| 2023-07-21 | Product B | 69.4792 |
| 2023-07-21 | Product C | 51.1961 |
| 2023-07-21 | Product D | 51.1961 |

Table 2 has stock data:

[image]

I want to have the product total, the available quantity multiplied with the latest date price, so that I can get the latest value of each available stock.

I want a result like this:

[image]

I tried the following query, but I have to change the value in `(b.TradingDate = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE(),103)))` when Saturday and Sunday comes, since there are no price data for Saturday and Sunday. -1 to -3 to get the price value of Friday. I want this to get auto-reflect as per the last and latest date price available.

```
select 
  a.party,
  a.product,
  a.accountNo,
  round(sum(a.net_invest),0) as TAmount,
  DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE(),103)) as PriceDate, 
  round(sum(a.Net_Units),3) as TUnits, 
  round(sum(a.Net_Units * b.nav),0) as Valuation
from Trans a, price b
where a.product = b.product 
  and b.TradingDate = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE(),103))
group by a.party, a.product, a.accountNo
order by a.party, a.product
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead paste the data as formatted text into your request.

Comment: Don't use comma joins. They have been deprecated for 30 years now. Since SQL standard 1992 to be precise. And don't use arbitrary alias names. Alias names are meant to help readability. Names like "a" and "b" do the opposite. Instead use mnemonic names like t for trans and p for price.

Comment: This is year 2023.  Please use proper `join`.

Comment: I converted the first table for you, please do the same for the others. Your description is not very clear, please work on it. You need to add tage for the SQL dialect you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting stock (which you call trans for some reason). This table contains products for which you want to get the most current price.

Then you want to aggregate the data so as to get one result row per party, product and account number.

You can use `ORDER BY` with `TOP` in a `CROSS APPLY` to get a product's latest price.

```
select 
    t.party,
    t.product,
    t.accountno,
    round(sum(t.net_invest), 0) as tamount,
    max(lp.tradingdate) as pricedate, 
    round(sum(t.net_units), 3) as tunits, 
    round(sum(t.net_units * lp.nav), 0) as valuation
from trans t
cross apply
(
    select top(1) p.tradingdate, p.nav
    from price p
    where p.product = t.product
    order by p.tradingdate desc
) lp
group by t.party, t.product, t.accountno
order by t.party, t.product;
```